# MATLAB newbie - Display Photos above panel in guide

Tags: matlab

i want to display photo above the panel , i see the documentation here : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html
but it only mention how to use this function (uistack) only in figure

my program till now :

[image]

my code :

```
function varargout = panel(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @panel_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @panel_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end


handles.output = hObject;


guidata(hObject, handles);





function varargout = panel_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 


varargout{1} = handles.output;



function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

k = 1;
[filename pathname]  = uigetfile({'*.*'},'File Selector','MultiSelect', 'on')
iscellstr(filename)
celldata1 = cellstr(pathname)
celldata2 = cellstr(filename)
celldata3 = strcat(celldata1,celldata2)
subplot(3,4,1),imshow(celldata3{1})
subplot(3,4,2),imshow(celldata3{2})
subplot(3,4,3),imshow(celldata3{3})
subplot(3,4,4),imshow(celldata3{4})
subplot(3,4,5),imshow(celldata3{5})
subplot(3,4,6),imshow(celldata3{6})
```

Comment: What Matlab version are you using?

Comment: matlab R2014b version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I asked for the version was that if you were using an older version (than R2014b) you could set the `BackgroundColor` property of the `uipanel` to be 'none' which would make it transparent.  This "feature" doesn't work in R2014b onwards...

```
%% Only HG1 (pre R2014b)
f = figure;
subplot ( 3, 3, 4 )
uipanel ( 'parent', f, 'Position', [0. 0. 0.6 0.6], 'BackgroundColor', 'none' );
```

Im afraid other options will require more knowledge of how GUI's work - specifically creating GUI's from the commandline (and not in GUIDE):

```
% Create a figure
f = figure;
% Create a uicontainer (this is a way of grouping controls together 
uic = uicontainer ( 'parent', f, 'position', [0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5] );
% Create an axes -> which is a child of the UICONTAINER
ax = axes ( 'parent', uic, 'position', [0 0 1 1] );
% Create a uipanel -> which is a chilf of the FIGURE
uipanel ( 'parent', f, 'position', [0 0 0.4 0.7] );
% Some data to plot
image(rand(100)*255,'parent',ax) 
% Note at this point the axes is underneath the uipanel
%%
% Hey presto we can move the uicontainer to the top and the axes appears! :)
uistack ( uic, 'top' )
```

**Note:** If you create the `uicontainer` after creating the `uipanel` then you dont need to use `uistack` - I put it in that order to show that uistack will move the *'axes'* in the stack order...

Comment: wooow i'm a newbie in matlab , i added f = figure; && uipanel ( 'parent', f, 'Position', [0. 0. 0.6 0.6], 'BackgroundColor', 'none' ); up and down of my sublot nothing changes :/

Comment: i noticed that this code create figure , but i dont need them i'm using the guide

Comment: What your trying to do can't be done with guide.  Maybe if you explain why you need your sub plot above a uipanel we can point you in a different direction to get what you want.

Comment: i only need to present my images above the panel that's all , cause it looks more efficient ,thanks

Comment: maybe you can help me in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014810/matlab-newbie-add-element-to-pop-up-menu

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've correctly undestood what you need, nevertheless ...

you can first create the panel (`uipanel`) specifying its position (which includes size), then create as many axes as you need (consider the number of imagery you want to add) in order to crate a sort of chessboard (you can do this by properly setting their position and size).

You can now load the images over the axis by specifying the `parent` property.

In the following example I create a uipanel which contains three images, notice the coupling "axes-handle - parent property" in the calls to imshow.

In the "`pushbutton1_Callback`" of your code, you can "automate" this procedure.

```
uipanel ('position', [0 0 0.33 0.95],'title','PLOK');
a1=axes('position',[0 0 .3 .3])
a2=axes('position',[0 0.3 .3 .3])
a3=axes('position',[0 0.6 .3 .3])

imshow('curva_con_linee_verticali.jpg','parent',a1)
imshow('grafico_3d_assi_cartesiani.jpg','parent',a2)
imshow('prod_punt.jpg','parent',a3)
```

This is how the Figure looks like (the three graphs are actually three jpg images):

[image]

Hope this helps.