# MATLAB newbie - add element to pop-up menu

Tags: matlab

i want to add element to my pop-up menu that user write it in a text field , i'm new to matlab so any explanation is very appreciated , i know it's about a callback in the pushbutton but i don't know how to do it exactly..

My gui so far :

[image]

my code so far :

```
function varargout = popupmenu(varargin)

gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @popupmenu_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @popupmenu_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end


function popupmenu_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

handles.output = hObject;


guidata(hObject, handles);





function varargout = popupmenu_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;



function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end


function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `pushbutton1_Callback`you might add:

```
new_item=get(handles.edit_1,'string') % to get the string from the edit box
tmp=get(handles.popupmenu1,'string') % to get the actual list of items in the popup menu
tmp{end+1}=new_item % to add the string
set(handles.popupmenu1,'string',tmp) % to update the popup menu items
```

Comment: maybe you can solve this also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916080/matlab-uistack-display-photos-in-panel
thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

i done it , in the callback button :

```
dropdownListStrings = {'item1',item2'}     
handleToListbox = uicontrol('Style', 'popup','Position', [20 60 200 60], 'String', dropdownListStrings);
```

but how to get the new data from the new popup menu ??

EDIT : 
found it

```
handleToListbox = uicontrol('Style', 'popup','Position', [20 60 200 60], 'String', dropdownListStrings,'Callback',@setmap);
function setmap(source,callbackdata)
val = source.Value
string = source.String(val)
end
```